# Jump crossing in circuitikz

Tags: nodes, circuitikz, tikz-node, circuits, node-connections

I wanted to draw a jumping node to the intersections of leg1 and voltage. If you can run the code you will probably understand why I mean. I tried to[crossing] and naming the intersection point then putting a node there, but the node is never in the place where I want. And actually I want a bigger jump, like shown in the right image. I would really appreciate any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=1.5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=1.5}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 1}\\
 \textbf{a.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw
    % Thyristors leg 2
    (5,4.5) to [open, v^=$V_o$] ++(0,-5)
    (2,0)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5)
        -- ++(0,1)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leg2)
    % Thyristors leg 1
    (0,0)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5)
        -- ++(0,1)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leg1)
    % Connections and load RL
        -- ++(4,0)
        to[short, f^=$\sqrt{2}\si{\ampere}$] ++(0,-1.5)
        to[R,l^=$R$] ++(0,-1)
    % Back to (0,0)
        |- (0,0)
    % AC source
    (-2,0) coordinate (Vnn)
        to[sV, l^=$230\sqrt{2}\sin{(2\pi 50t)}$] ++(0,4)
        to [short] (-1,4)
        to [short] ++(0,-1.6) coordinate (Vpp)
        -- (leg1 |- Vpp) node [circ] {}
    (Vnn) to [short] (-1,0)
        to [short] ++(0,1.6) coordinate (Vxx)
        -- ++(3,0) node [circ] {}
    % capasitor
    (3,4) 
        to[short, f^=$I_C$, current/distance=0.5] ++(0,-1.5)
        to[curved capacitor,l^=$C$] ++(0,-1)
        -- ++(0,-1.5)
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crossing` element is positioned at the center of the segment where the `to` is drawn. The size is controlled by the key `bipoles/crossing/size`, which defaults to `0.2`. One possibility, if I understood correctly, is this:

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=1.5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=1.5}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 1}\\
 \textbf{a.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
    % Thyristors leg 2
    (5,4.5) to [open, v^=$V_o$] ++(0,-5)
    (2,0)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5)
        -- ++(0,1)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leg2)
    % Thyristors leg 1
    (0,0)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5)
        -- ++(0,1)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leg1)
    % Connections and load RL
        -- ++(4,0)
        to[short, f^=$\sqrt{2}\si{\ampere}$] ++(0,-1.5)
        to[R,l^=$R$] ++(0,-1)
    % Back to (0,0)
        |- (0,0)
    % AC source
    (-2,0) coordinate (Vnn)
        to[sV, l^=$230\sqrt{2}\sin{(2\pi 50t)}$] ++(0,4)
        to [short] (-1,4)
        to [short] ++(0,-1.6) coordinate (Vpp)
        -- (leg1 |- Vpp) node [circ] {}
    (Vnn) to [short] (-1,0)
        to [short] ++(0,1.6) coordinate (Vxx)
        % the jump crossing should be at (Vxx|-leg1), move symmetrically around
        ([xshift=-0.5cm]Vxx -| leg1) to[crossing, bipoles/crossing/size=1] 
            ([xshift=0.5cm]Vxx -| leg1)
        % left and right connections
        ([xshift=-0.5cm]Vxx -| leg1)  -- (Vxx)
        ([xshift=0.5cm]Vxx -| leg1) -- (Vxx -| leg2) node[circ]{}
    % capasitor
    (3,4)
        to[short, f^=$I_C$, current/distance=0.5] ++(0,-1.5)
        to[curved capacitor,l^=$C$] ++(0,-1)
        -- ++(0,-1.5)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A cleaner solution would be using a `xing` node by positioning it at `(Vxx -| leg1)` before drawing the vertical or horizontal line and then going from there (but you should reorganize your drawing so that you define `Vxx` earlier)

Comment: BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, and should not be used in Ti*k*Z...

Comment: I understood it very well, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to draw a white filled area over a previously drawn crossing, then add the `jump crossing` node.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=1.5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=1.5}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question 1}\\
 \textbf{a.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw
    % Thyristors leg 2
    (5,4.5) to [open, v^=$V_o$] ++(0,-5)
    (2,0)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5)
        -- ++(0,1)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leg2)
    % Thyristors leg 1
    (0,0)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5)
        -- ++(0,1)
        to[D] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leg1)
    % Connections and load RL
        -- ++(4,0)
        to[short, f^=$\sqrt{2}\si{\ampere}$] ++(0,-1.5)
        to[R,l^=$R$] ++(0,-1)
    % Back to (0,0)
        |- (0,0)
    % AC source
    (-2,0) coordinate (Vnn)
        to[sV, l^=$230\sqrt{2}\sin{(2\pi 50t)}$] ++(0,4)
        to [short] (-1,4)
        to [short] ++(0,-1.6) coordinate (Vpp)
        -- (leg1 |- Vpp) node [circ] {}
    (Vnn) to [short] (-1,0)
        to [short] ++(0,1.6) coordinate (Vxx)
        -- ++(3,0) node [circ] {}
    % capasitor
    (3,4) 
        to[short, f^=$I_C$, current/distance=0.5] ++(0,-1.5)
        to[curved capacitor,l^=$C$] ++(0,-1)
        -- ++(0,-1.5)
    ;
  \path (0,1.6) node[fill=white][circle]{} node[draw, jump crossing,scale=5]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: demo]