Creating Half-Circle Indications for Crossing Wires in Circuitikz Diagrams
Could someone please guide me on how to modify my code to achieve the DESIRED OUTPUT below with a half-circle for the wire crossing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
CODE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}
        
        \draw (0,0)
        to[R=$R_2$] (8,0);
        
        \draw (2,2)
        to[R=$R_3$] (2,-5);
        
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}

OUTPUT:

DESIRED OUTPUT:


Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334483/86 and its linked questions. The spath3 solutions now work with code on ctan so don't need code downloading from github.

Maybe have a look if https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzdotncross might help

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702698/jump-crossing-in-circuitikz

You can use node[jump crossing]{}, as described at the section 4.10 Crossings of the circuitikz manual.
Example (not exactly the desired one, but close):
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}

      \node at (2,0)[jump crossing](X){};

      \draw (0,0) -- (X.west);
      \draw (X.east) to[R=$R_2$] (8,0);

      \draw (2,2)
      to[R=$R_3$] (2,-5);

    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}


EDIT I was too lazy to reproduced exactly the desired output, but after @Rmano's comment, here is an attempt:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}

      \node at (2,0)[jump crossing, rotate=90](X){};

      \draw (0,0)
      to[R=$R_2$] (8,0);

      \draw (2,2)
      to (X.east);
      \draw (X.west)
      to[R=$R_3$] ++(0,-2)
      to (2,-5);

    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}



Add a rotate=90 to the node and then adjust the rest and you'll have exactly the requested drawing...

@Rmano Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer.
